# How complement of ETM is semidecidable

Tags: turing-machines, reductions, semi-decidability

If ETM = {＜M＞ ∣ M is a Turing Machine and L(M) = ∅}, how can I prove that the complement of ETM is semi-decidable?

Comment: Are you familiar with [dovetailing](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/64264/dovetailing-in-turing-machines)?

Comment: No, I never heard about it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to find a way to enumerate the elements of $\overline{ETM}$. One way is to create a procedure which, in stage $n$, tests the first $n$ Turing machines for the first $n$ inputs for $n$ steps, outputing the code of a machine if it finds an input it accepts. If $M\in\overline{ETM}$, then, eventually, your procedure will find $M$, the input it accepts, and be in a stage where it simulates $M$ for enough steps.

Now, to see that it is semi-decidable and not decidable, you can, for example, find a reduction from the Halting problem to ETM.
One possible way is to, given a machine $M$, construct a machine $M'$, which accepts an input $x$ whenever $M$ accepts $0$. Then, $L(M')$ is either $\mathbb{N}$ or $\emptyset$ and $M\in HALT$ if and only if $M'\in\overline{ETM}$.

Are you familiar with these constructions?

Comment: Why M∈~ETM not the string accepted by the TM M?

Comment: So  we should prove that the complement of ETM is not decidable, then we should prove it is semidecidable through the reduction step with Halting machine?

Comment: The reduction is where you prove that it is not decidable. Essentially, you prove that, if you could decide ETM (or its complement), then you could decide the Halting problem, which you can't. This proves that ETM and its complement are not decidable (if a set is decidable, so is its complement), whence it is at least as hard as the Halting problem. Now, to prove that $\overline{ETM}$ is semi-decidable you have to show that it is not harder than the Halting problem. One way of doing this is with the enumeration I mentioend. Did this help?

Answer (score 0):

Consider an alphabet $\Sigma$, and let $w_1, w_2, w_3, \ldots$ denote all words in $\Sigma^*$ in *minlex* order, that is, for all $i < j$, one of the following holds: (1) either $|w_i| < |w_j|$, or (2) both $w_i$ and $w_j$ are of the same length, yet $w_i$ comes before $w_j$ in the lexicographic order. For example, $b <_{minlex} aa <_{minlex} ab$.

Now to show that $\overline{E_{TM}} \in \text{RE}$, we define a TM $T$ that, on input $\langle M\rangle$, simulates the run of $T$ on all words in $\Sigma^*$ in parallel, and checks if $M$ accepts at least one word, where $\Sigma$ is the input-alphabet of $M$.
Formally, $T$ works in iterations $i = 1, 2, \ldots$, where in iteration $i$, $T$ simulates the run of $M$ on the words $w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_i$, for $i$ steps each. If $M$ accepts one of the words $w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_i$ within $i$ steps, then $T$ halts and accepts, otherwise, $T$ proceeds to the next iteration.
So in the $i$'th iteration, we simulate the run of $M$ on the first $i$ words in minlex order.

Regarding correctness, if $T$ accepts in some iteration $i$, the clearly, one of the words $w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_i$ is accepted by $M$ and thus $L(M)\neq \emptyset$. Conversely, if $L(M)\neq \emptyset$, then there is $j\geq 1$ such that $w_j\in L(M)$. Let $t$ denote the number of steps that takes the machine $M$ to accept $w_j$, and consider $i = \max(t, j)$. Clearly, $w_j$ is one of the first $i$ words in minlex order. If $T$ survived all iterations and reached iteration number $i$ and got to the point where it simulates the run of $M$ on $w_j$ for $i \geq t$ steps, then it halts an accepts as $M$ accepts $w_j$ within $t$ steps, in particular, within $i$ steps.

**Notes:**

1- The fact that we traverse all words in $\Sigma^*$ in minlex order is crucial. For example, if $\Sigma = \{ a, b\}$, and we traverse all words following a lexicographic order, then if $M$ accepts only the input $b$, we will never find that out, as there are infinitely many words that start with $a$.

2- Note that $T$ need not halt, when $L(M)$ is empty, but this is okay as we're showing that $\overline{E_{TM}} \in \text{RE}$. In fact, we cannot do better as the language is not decidable.